# Trouble with number formats

Tags: vba, excel, format, decimal

I have the following code:

```
Dim tarifa As Double
tarifa = Sheets("OD Tarifa").Cells(fila, 5 + r).value
Cells(j, r + 10).FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=" & tarifa & "-" & "SUMIF(C[-6],RC[-6],C[-3])+SUMIF(C[-6],RC[-6],C[-2])+SUMIF(C[-6],RC[-6],C[-1])"
```

Where `tarifa` is saved using a comma as decimal separator (1,5 for example), so when VBA tries to write the formula, it throws an error. If I manually replace `tarifa` for a 1.5 for example, there is no error. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I finally solved it:

```
Dim tarifa As Double
tarifa = Sheets("OD Tarifa").Cells(fila, 5 + r).value
Cells(j, r + 10).FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=""" & CStr(tarifa) & """-" & "SUMIF(C[-6],RC[-6],C[-3])+SUMIF(C[-6],RC[-6],C[-2])+SUMIF(C[-6],RC[-6],C[-1])"
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use `FormulaR1C1Local` instead of `FormulaR1C1`:

```
Dim tarifa As Double
tarifa = Cells(1, 2).Value
Cells(2, 2).FormulaR1C1Local = "=" & tarifa
```

Comment: This did not work since the original language of the Excel fil is not english and hence it did not recognise the formulas (given that they are in english). I solved it by replacing tarifa with CStr(tarifa).

Answer (score 1):

If in Excel 2013 or later, try using the [`NUMBERVALUE`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/NUMBERVALUE-function-1b05c8cf-2bfa-4437-af70-596c7ea7d879) function. It allows you to specify the decimal and thousands separator in a number you're reading. I think it would work here to allow you to switch from the comma decimal-separator to the period that VBA wants:

```
tarifa = worksheetfunction.NumberValue(Sheets("OD Tarifa").Cells(fila, 5 + r).value,",",".")
```

If that's not applicable you should be able to fix it with a find and replace:

```
tarifa = replace((Sheets("OD Tarifa").Cells(fila, 5 + r).value,",",".")
```

Comment: This might have worked but I finally solved it by replacing tarifa with CStr(tarifa).